# Orchard menu item rendering: two different menus that need different html classes

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have 2 menus that are being conditionally rendered in Orchard via authenticated state (Whether the user is logged in or not).

The challenge I am having is how to control the rendering of each menu at an html class level. Each menu has a slightly different html structure with different classes for different CSS designs.

At present both menus use the same menu.cshtml and MenuItem.cshtml files that are sitting in the theme's root folder.

What is the best way to individually control the html classes and structure for each specific menu?

Menu 1:

```
        <!--Main Menu HTML Code-->
         <nav class="wsmenu slideLeft clearfix">
              <ul class="mobile-sub wsmenu-list">
                <!-- List Item Ends -->
                  <li class="twelve-point">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p class="r-font-nav">L</p>
                    <h5>MEMBERSHIP</h5>
                  </a>
                    <ul class="wsmenu-submenu">
                      <li><a href="#"></i>ABOUT US</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i>CODES OF PRACTICE</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i>JOIN</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i>MEMBERSHIP</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i>BECOME A MEMBER</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"></i> MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
             <!-- List Item Ends -->
```

Menu 2:

```
  <!--Main Menu HTML Code-->
                            <div class="public-nav">
                                <nav class="wsmenu slideLeft clearfix">
                                    <ul class="mobile-sub wsmenu-list">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
                                            <ul class="wsmenu-submenu">
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>DIFFERENT</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>PRACTICE</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>POOLS</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>MEMBERSHIP OVERVIEW</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>MAPS</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#"></i>PARK MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                       </ul>
                                      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement IShapeTableProvider (It has a single method).
In this method your can add any kind of shape alternates.

For using services inside method you should inject it through ctor and probably wrap in Work class.

```
public class SomeShapeTableProvider : IShapeTableProvider
{
    private readonly Work<IAuthenticationService> _authenticationService;

    public SomeShapeTableProvider(Work<IAuthenticationService> authenticationService) {
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        // add alternates
    }
}
```

Then you should imlement Discover method like this:

```
public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Describe("MenuItem")
        .OnDisplaying(displaying => {
            if(_authenticationService.Value.GetAuthenticatedUser() != null)
                displaying.Shape.Metadata.Alternates.Add("MenuItem__Authenticated");
        });
}
```

And then you can use different shape for authenticated users `MenuItem-Authenticated.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

Give each of them unique extra class in nav tag so you can control each of them. 
Like:

```
<nav class="wsmenu menu_1 slideLeft clearfix">
<nav class="wsmenu menu_2 slideLeft clearfix">
```

Comment: That works for CSS. However, this question relates to controlling the html class attribute values through the Orchard alternate files.

This means that I have to customize MenuItem.cshtml,
Menu.cshtml and MenuItemLink.cshtml based on some kind of conditional. That is what I am trying to figure out. 



How to associate a zone or shape to a copy of these specific set of files.

Comment: In other words .... I have 2 menus. 

How can I associate one menu to an alternate/shape and the 2nd menu to another alternate/shape file.